# Execute shell program with execv

Tags: c, shell, exec

I'm writing in C langage a program that contain these lines:

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char* file=argv[1];
    char* arguments[] = { "sh", argv[2], argv[3], argv[4], file, NULL };
    execv("/bin/sh", arguments);  
}
```

The file is `prog.sh` which contain a simple sum of arguments:

```
expr $1 + $2 + $3
```

When I run the program by `./main prog.sh 1 2 3` I obtain an error which is

```
/bin/sh: 0: Can't open 1
```

While I expect the output 6 (sum of 1 2 3)

Comment: Do you have this code compiled? Into `expr` executable. And it looks *extremely* awkward. You have a shell script, calling an executable which is calling a shell script, calling the executable... It won't end peacefully.

Comment: When I run (sh prog.sh 1 2 3) from terminal it works. No, I have just a C program calling a shell script :)

Comment: What's `main` at all?

Comment: my main program !

Comment: In C, the return type of `main()` must be **`int`**, not `void`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your arguments:

```
char* arguments[] = { "sh", argv[2],argv[3],argv[4],file, NULL };
```

When you run `./main prog.sh 1 2 3`, you end up calling:

```
sh 1 2 3 prog.sh
```

You should instead make the script the first argument:

```
char* arguments[] = { "sh", file, argv[2],argv[3],argv[4], NULL };
```

thereby calling

```
sh prog.sh 1 2 3
```

Comment: I wonder why doesn't `"sh"` need a `"-c"` after it. Spent some time trying to get it to work WITH `"-c"`.

Comment: @VictorSergienko `-c` is for when you want to evaluate the shell code in a string. Don't use it if you want to evaluate shell code in a file (aka a script)